# How to find the dimensions of a List<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, arrays, list

I want to loop through the a List of  List>

I need to find the ceiling of the list so I can use it in the For statement

This is my code and I dont know what to use in the last line

```
**List<HashMap<String, String>> listMsgs = null;

listMsgs = msgsXmlParser.detparse(reader);

for(int i=0; i< listMsgs.**
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to be rectangular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> listMsgs = null;
        listMsgs.size();
        //size of collection
        for(HashMap<String, String> lMap : listMsgs) 
        //iterating through collection
        {
            lMap.size();
            //size of map
            for(String lKey : lMap.keySet()) 
            //iterating through map keyset
            {
                lMap.get(lKey);
                //key value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use `listMsgs.size()` or you can do this:

```
for (Map<String, String> map : listMsgs) {
    // work with map here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`listMsgs.size()` will give you a number of HashMaps in the list

`listMsgs.get(i).size()` will give you the size of HashMap at index i